# How do you delete children records with multiple belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My models look like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :entries
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :entries
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :project
end
```

I want to delete every Entry that depends on a Project when it gets deleted. I'm using Postgres with UUID's as their ID's. I've tried this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :entries

 before_destroy { |project| Entry.destroy_all "project_id = #{project.id}" }
end
```

But when the project gets deleted, the entries are still there. I think the reason would be that they still have another parent object.

I also tried to delete them from my controller:

```
def destroy
   @project = current_company.projects.find(params[:id])
   @project.time_entries.delete_all
   ...
end
```

What's the problem, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy` should work. However, it all depends on how you remove the `project`. If you say

```
@project.delete
```

then it will never work, as [delete](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete) skips the callbacks, which would remove all the `entries`. Instead, try using something like

```
@project.destroy
```

then it should work as [destroy](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy) does call callbacks. BTW, the same rules holds true for the `delete_all` and `destroy_all` variants.

Comment: wow, my bad, I didn't realize there was a difference between those 2 methods. thanks for clarifying that!